# Numpy: how to simulate propagation in a lattice

Tags: python, numpy

Here's the inefficient Python code I have:

```
import numpy as np 
import random  

matrix = np.empty( (100,100), dtype=bool )

matrix[:,:] = False
matrix[50,50] = True

def propagate(matrix, i, j):
    for (di,dj) in [ (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1) ]:
        (ni,nj) = (i+di, j+dj)
        if matrix[ni,nj] and flip_coin_is_face():
              matrix[i,j] = True 

def flip_coin_is_face():
    return random.uniform(0,1) < 0.5

for k in xrange(1000):
   for i in xrange(1,99):
      for j in xrange(1,99):
          propagate(matrix, i, j)
```

which basically propagates the True state from the center of the matrix. Since I'm coding the loops and the propagation rule in Python, this is of course very slow.

My question is, how can I use Numpy indexing to make this as fast as possible?

Comment: I ran your code and it ends up with a matrix where [0,0] is True and the rest is all false.  Surely this is not what you want?

Comment: @JohnZwinck based on `propagates the True state from the center of the matrix` i suppose it should be `matrix[50,50] = True` instead of `matrix[0,0] = True`

Comment: @JohnZwinck at-alko You are both right.

Comment: I edited the code to say 50,50 but I think it is still wrong due to the ranges used at the bottom.  Well, I'm not gonna play psychic anymore on this one.

Comment: You could try using the `numpy.gradient` function, applying some boolean test to the result, generating a boolean matrix, making some operation back to the original matrix. It would be sort of an "edge detector" where you could expand the edges into the original matrix.

Comment: Also, you could use `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation`.

Comment: The way to do this in 2019 is via http://numba.pydata.org/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of one approach, but it differs with your original code. Namely, you can filter ones in each step array (`k` loop), propagate each value to its neiboughours, i.e. roll dice 4 times number of ones, and evaluate next step array. Each operation can be done with a numpy one liner (using `where`, `reshape`, `+` and `*` for matrices), so there will be no inner loops.

Difference lies in fact that we do not take into account values, propagated within a step, evaluating all changes at once. In fact, it will slow down, and I suppose noticeably, propagation speed in terms of steps required to fulfill all the matrix.

If this approach is ok, I can come up with some code.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I think I can take it from there.... In fact, now that I think about it "do not take into account (in-step propagated) values" is the correct way to go for my problem....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great with numpy, but to "propagate" through the matrix, you can use something like a breadth-first search. If you haven't used it before, it looks like this:

```
import Queue

def neighbors(i, j, mat_shape):
    rows = mat_shape[0]
    cols = mat_shape[1]
    offsets = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
    neighbors = []
    for off in offsets:
        r = off[0]+i
        c = off[1]+j
        if 0 <= r and r <= rows and 0 <= c and c <= cols:
            neighbors.append((r,c))
    return neighbors

def propagate(matrix, i, j):
    # 'parents' is used in two ways. first, it tells us where we've already been
    #  second, it tells us w
    parents = np.empty(matrix.shape)
    parents[:,:] = None
    # first-in-first-out queue. initially it just has the start point
    Q = Queue.Queue()
    # do the first step manually; start propagation with neighbors
    matrix[i,j] = True
    for n in neighbors(i,j,matrix.shape):
        Q.put(n)
        parents[n[0],n[1]] = (i,j)
    # initialization done. on to the propagation
    while not Q.empty():
        current = Q.get() # get's front element and removes it
        parent = parents[current[0], current[1]]
        matrix[current[0], current[1]] = matrix[parent[0], parent[1]] and flip_coin_is_face()
        # propagate to neighbors, in order
        for next in neighbors(current[0], current[1], matrix.shape):
            # only propagate there if we haven't already
            if parents[next[0], next[1]] is None:
                parents[next[0], next[1]] = current
                Q.put(next)
    return matrix
```

You can probably be more clever and cut off the propagation early (since once it gets to `False`, it will never get `True` again). But for 100x100, this should be plenty fast.

Comment: I'm looking for something more in the way of numpy indexing... I'm afraid that a Queue won't help as much in this case as having some C code behind the numpy implementation to do the work...Anyway, thanks for your attention.